# I propose a sandbox for answers

Tags: discussion, sandbox

Similar to

[Sandbox for proposed questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5832/34768)

I propose a sandbox for answers.

I have provided an example below of what a sandbox answer might look like.

What does the community think about it?

---

[Are there any reliable indications on popular sentiment in Afghanistan for/against the Taliban?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68078/34768)

> A 2013 survey based on interviews of 38,000 Muslims, randomly selected from urban and rural parts in 39 countries using area probability designs, by the Pew Forum on Religion and Public Life found that a majority—in some cases "overwhelming" majority—of Muslims in a number of countries support making "Sharia" or "Islamic law" the law of the land, including Afghanistan (99%), .......

[Sharia - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia)

> The Taliban's ideology has been described as combining an "innovative" form of sharia Islamic law.....

[Taliban - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taliban)

Statement 1: A vast majority of the people of Afganistan wants Sharia to be the law of the land.

Statement 2: Taliban wants to govern the country based on Sharia.

So, it logically follows a vast majority of the people of Afghanistan favors the Taliban government.

Comment: And also you are free to delete any answer that is negatively received so you don't need to waste people's time with a sandbox.

Comment: What's up with -5?

Comment: People are expressing the fact that they don't agree with this idea

Comment: @JoeW Okay. I am one of the minorities. We shall see people welcoming this soon.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to say no to this as it would be very complicated for very little gain. In order for this to work you would have to include both the question and the answer and keep the question updated to any changes. I would also question if this would get any use or value at all as the question you linked to has a total of 4 questions posted to it in 2 months of life. If you look at that question it has a total of 172 views which means there is not a lot of feedback provided for those questions.

In the end I just see this as providing little value as the meta site gets very little traffic and it will just die out.

Your example shows the problem with this sandbox as anyone who wants judge if it is a good example first has to take time to load the question and read it in a different window than the answer. At a minimum an answer posted in this sandbox has to include both the question and the answer and depending on the length that will not be possible.